# Ambiguity of “not.... because”

Tags: ambiguity

> You are not hired because you are qualified.

I think this means you are hired but it is not because you are qualified. But I think this can  also means you are not hired, and the reason for it is that you are qualified.

Does this ambiguity really exist or do I mistake anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is ambiguity:

> When a sentence containing a clause-modifying adjunct, such as a because
>   clause, is negated, the resulting example is ambiguous.
>   <sub>[Because clauses and negative polarity licensing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.1782&rep=rep1&type=pdf)</sub>

The paper uses the terms "Negated Head" and "Negated Adjunct" to describe the two readings:

NH: You are not hired and the reason is you are qualified.
NA: You are hired but not because you are qualified.

> In the NH readings, it is the head proposition which is negated. In the NA readings, it is the relation introduced by the adjunct which is negated.

---

The ambiguity can be eliminated by rewording the sentence. The NA version is fine, but the NH one is awkward. Instead, try inverting the sentence:

> Because you are qualified, you are not hired.